# My UIPickerView is loading the same data from core data again and again,Needs to load it once only

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uipickerview

My UIPickerView is loading the same data from core data again and again,Needs to load it once only.
I am using pickerView to load the stores but even after disabling the data,its loading the same stores multiple times.

Please let me know,where i can correct my program

Below is my code :-

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ItemDetailsVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var storePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsField: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceField: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleField: CustomTextField!
    var stores = [Store]()
    var itemToEdit: Item?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        storePicker.delegate = self
        storePicker.dataSource = self
//        let store = Store(context: context)
//        store.name = "Amazon"
//        let store1 = Store(context: context)
//        store1.name = "Flipkart"
//        let store2 = Store(context: context)
//        store2.name = "Snapdeal"
//        let store3 = Store(context: context)
//        store3.name = "Bigbasket"
//        let store4 = Store(context: context)
//        store4.name = "Groffers"
//        ad.saveContext()
        getStores()

        if itemToEdit != nil{
            loadItemData()
        }

        if let topItem = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem {
            topItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        let store = stores[row]
        return store.name
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return stores.count
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        //Update
    }

    func getStores(){
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Store> = Store.fetchRequest()
        do{
            self.stores = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            self.storePicker.reloadAllComponents()
        }catch{
            //Handles the error
        }
    }

    @IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: Any) {

        var item: Item!
        if itemToEdit == nil{
            item = Item(context: context)
        }else{
            item = itemToEdit
        }

        if let title = titleField.text{
            item.title = title
        }
        if let price = priceField.text{
            item.price = (price as NSString).doubleValue
        }
        if let details = detailsField.text{
            item.details = details
        }
        item.toStore = stores[storePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    func loadItemData(){
        if let item = itemToEdit{
            titleField.text = item.title
            priceField.text = "\(item.price)"
            detailsField.text = item.details

            if let store = item.toStore{
                var index = 0
                repeat{
                    let s = stores[index]
                    if s.name == store.name{
                        storePicker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
                        break
                        }
                    index += 1
                }while index < stores.count
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that your picker contains more rows than you expect, with duplicated data?  I would presume that this is because you have added the records to your core data store multiple times; delete your app to clear the core data and run it again.

Comment: I deleted the app but still getting the same, it's getting added automatically, initially it contains only once

Comment: Check your code where you add the data; does that data get added each time you run the app?